# Si me bloquean de hacer preguntas en Stack Overflow en inglés, ¿tambien me bloquean de los otros sitios de Stack Exchange?

Tags: soporte, stackexchange, bloqueo-de-publicación

Si por alguna razon en Stack Overflow en inglés me indican que soy candidato a ser bloqueado de hacer preguntas (probablemente por mi bajo nivel de inglés), ¿este bloqueo puede afectar a los otros sitios de la red de Stack Exchange o solo me afecta en el sitio donde recibí dicha advertencia?

Mensaje de advertencia que he recibido:

> Wait! Some of your past questions have not been well-received, and you're in danger of being blocked from asking any more.
>
> For help formulating a clear, useful question, see: How do I ask a good question?
>
> Also, edit your previous questions to improve formatting and clarity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Los bloqueos de publicar preguntas o respuestas se basan en tu participación en un sitio concreto, por lo que aplican solamente a ese sitio.

En [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/209901) (inglés) se explica toda la casuística. Básicamente, hay un algoritmo que va valorando la calidad de lo que publicas. Si se cierran, votan o eliminan tus publicaciones, ese número irá bajando. Si es peligrosamente bajo, te avisarán; si cae al fondo, se te bloqueará automáticamente por parte del sistema. Ese bloqueo te impedirá publicar o bien preguntas o bien respuestas (o ambas) hasta que tu puntuación mejore. Esas mejoras solo podrán producirse en base a mejoras que hagas en las publicaciones que publicaste en el pasado.

Si bien no se explicita que el bloqueo sea únicamente en un sitio, a mí me parece obvio: si se basa en tus publicaciones en ese sitio, el algoritmo no tendrá en cuenta lo que hagas en otro.

Un caso aparte sería la suspensión: esa se realiza manualmente por los moderadores o empleados de Stack Exchange y sí puede llegar a afectar a todos los sitios de la red. Esas suspensiones son temporales, por lo que pasados X días, semanas o años podrás volver a publicar con normalidad.

Comment: ... dicho lo cual, lo mejor a hacer en estos casos es editar tus publicaciones previas para que estén en un formato aceptable para ese sitio.